# How to copy XML tag data into another branch in same XML

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I have this XML like below:

```
    <xs:VehicleData>
      <xdd:myData>1234</xdd:myData>
      <xdd:SrcUsrAge>34</xdd:SrcUsrAge>
      <xdd:array>
       ....
       .......
        .....
         <xdd:SrcAge></xdd:SrcAge>
      </xdd:array>
    .....
    </xs:vehicleData>
```

I tryint to copy the age 34 into SrcAge tag using XSLT. I am unable to do it. Newbie to XSLT. Can you help? Really Appreciate it.This is not an assignment.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortenately you need to copy all existing nodes to add only one node to this XML using XSLT, here is sample XSL as you asked:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://xs.example.com/"
    xmlns:xdd="http://xdd.example.com/" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="xs:vehicleData">
            <xsl:variable name="srcUsrAge" select="//xdd:SrcUsrAge/text()"/>
            <xsl:element name="xdd:myData">
                <xsl:value-of select="//xdd:myData/text()"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="xdd:SrcUsrAge">
                <xsl:value-of select="$srcUsrAge"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="xdd:array">
                <xsl:element name="xdd:SrcAge">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$srcUsrAge"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I had to declare testing namespaces to work with your XML:

```
xmlns:xs="http://xs.example.com/"
xmlns:xdd="http://xdd.example.com/"
```

feel free to change them.

Comment: This is how it is producing the output.                                                      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:vehicleData xmlns:xs="http://xmlns.example.com/XMLSchema/ETL/x.xsd">
   <xdd:myData xmlns:xdd="http://xmlns.example.com/XMLSchema/COMMON/XMLDataDictionary.xsd">1234</xdd:myData>
   <xdd:SrcUsrAge xmlns:xdd="http://xmlns.example.com/XMLSchema/COMMON/x.xsd">34</xdd:SrcUsrAge>
   <xdd:array xmlns:xdd="http://xmlns.example.com/XMLSchema/COMMON/XMLDataDictionary.xsd">
      <xdd:SrcAge>34</xdd:SrcAge>
   </xdd:array>
</xs:vehicleData>